# sklearn.cluster KMeans different result in different computer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I am using K-means algorithm in python sklearn.cluster.

I am aware that because of the initialization, results can be different every time. But I am also aware that with enough runs the results should not be so different each time.

But the thing is for computer #1, it yields cluster #1 every time I run it. And for computer #2, it yields cluster #2 everytime I run it.

The problem is that cluster #1 and cluster #2 are not the same. The code and data are exactly the same as I copy and pasted them.

They are not significantly different but they are different enough to cause some problem in my entire algorithm.

computer #1 and computer #2 both uses gpu and cpu. But computer #1 is much more powerful in terms of computing power.

code below

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

sc = StandardScaler()
X_sc = sc.fit_transform(X)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 5, init = 'k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state = 0)
X_k = kmeans.fit_predict(X_sc)
```

X_k is different for different computers.
same every time for individual computer.

Comment: Could you post a snippet of your code? For my it is still quite unclear, what you are doing and trying

Comment: @PV8 just a standard kmeans clustering code. should not be so different but when I print X_k the clustered items are quite different.

Comment: one idea would be, to run it for max_iter=10, and n_init=5, maybe this is a problem at one of the computers

Comment: is the same version of `sklearn` installed on both systems ?

Comment: @PV8 I don't think the parameters were the problem. But I tried rebooting one of my computers, the results got a lot closer. Maybe has to do with memory problem... verisons were in fact different. The one I think had a problem was version 0.22 and the other one was version 0.21.3. But I don't think the version should have caused much problem either... What do you think?

Comment: @makis I updated my version to 0.22.1 and it did make some difference to the clusters. But I think originally it was a memory problem.